# Why is innerHTML for root component not working

Tags: vuejs3

i created an app where its html is contained in the apps root element. The documentation says:
'Vue will automatically use the container's innerHTML as the template if the root component does not already have a template option.'  (see https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#mounting-the-app). But its not working. It displays only the first part up to the first occurence of the rwy component (see code below). If instead i  put this html in the template option of the object which is the argument of createApp() it works! What is wrong with my code? Thank you for help :-)

```
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": { "vue": "./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-browser.js" }
  }
</script>

        <label for="app">Web-Component 'RWY-Display'</label>
        <div class="rbox" id="app">
                <div>
                <h1>Runway 1</h1>
                <rwy id="rwy07C25C" rwy1="07C" rwy2="25C" />

                <h1>Runway 2</h1>
                <rwy id="rwy07R25L" rwy1="07R" rwy2="25L" />
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="module"  >
  import { createApp } from 'vue'
  import Rwy from './Rwy.js'

  var myApp = createApp({
        components: { 'rwy':Rwy }
  });
  myApp.mount('#app');
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is that self-closing brackets are only available in SFCs. The switching from `<rwy/>` to  `<rwy></rwy/>` should resolve your issue.

[docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats)

[image: we must always include explicit closing tags]

```js
  const { createApp } = Vue;
  var myApp = createApp({
    setup(props){
      return{}
    }
  });
  
  myApp.component("rwy", {
    template: `<div></div>`
  });
  myApp.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h1>Runway 1</h1>
    <rwy id="rwy07C25C"></rwy>

    <h1>Runway 2</h1>
    <rwy id="rwy07R25L"></rwy>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A key detail I had to discover is where the docs say "When using Vue without a build step, we can write our root component's template directly inside the mount container" under Creating an Application. I am using a build step (webpack) and the template compiler is not included. When using a build step, you need to include Vue (and some dependent libraries like Vuex) as script tags, and list the libraries as externals in your webpack config, in order to support parsing your root component template from innerHTML.